# Render LayoutGrid of child article in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco

I have a article witch has multiple related article. this related articles have a layout grid. now I want to render this grids below of my main article. 
I get this related article by this code:

```
 @{
     var children = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("relatedArticles").ToString().Split(',');
  }
  @foreach (var child in children) {
      Umbraco.Content(child).GetGridHtml("gridLayout");
  }
```

but GetGridHtml() function donot work. in umbraco documentation **GetGridHtml**
only is accesible from @CurrentPage.
how can I render these grid layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my solution by using this method:

```
@{
     var children = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("relatedArticles").ToString().Split(',');
 }
 @foreach (var child in children) {
      var data = Umbraco.TypedContent(child);
      @Html.GetGridHtml(data, "gridLayout");
 }
```

Comment: If you use Umbraco.TypedContent instead of .Content it will return an IPublishedContent (so no need to cast it). Also you should check if your data variable is null because the node could have been deleted but its ID could still be in the relatedArticles property